# Как установить программно фокус в строку поиска Яндекса в WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

В разметке Activity есть виджет WebView.
Загружаю в него страницу "http://yandex.ru".
Загружается без проблем.

Вопрос:
Как передать программно фокус в строку поиска Яндекса, чтобы в этой строке маркер моргал и открывалась клавиатура?

Answer (score 1):

Надо сбацать что-то типа:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('fieldName')[0].focus();");
```

где `fieldName` - это имя строки поиска в html документе страницы Яндекса (можно подсмотреть в HTML коде страницы)